# Push data to queue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

Laravel App checks redis database for data pushed by 3rd Party.

Laravel Scheduler runs artisan command `php artisan check:redis` every 10 mins.

I am expecting about 20k records to be checked every hour at peak times. Please also suggest me if my whole approach as a whole is flawed.

1. Scheduler runs `check:redis` command every 10 mins
2. `check:redis` command should dispatch job to be queued
3. Queue will later process jobs and create rows as required.

Below is `handle()` method from `App\Console\Commands\CheckRedis`

```
public function handle()
{
  while(Redis::llen('schema_queue')){
    dispatch(new CheckRedisJob($redis->rpop('schema_queue')))
  }
}
```

and this is `App\Jobs\CheckRedisJob`

```
public function handle()
{
    Stage::create([
        'model' => $this->entity->model,
        'payload' => json_encode($this->entity->payload)
    ]);
}
```

Now when I run the command, instead of queuing, it's directly creating what's in `Stage::create()`

*Sidenote: Each job dispatched will have a Model name & payload and will be dynamically inserted to specified table by validating and/or checking as required which obviously takes time.(below is sample model/payload) That's where the whole idea of processing the Job Queue is.*

```
{
  model : "Profession",
  payload: {
              id: '......',
              name: '........',
              contract_type: '........',
              employment_type: '........',
              department: '........'
              .... and like 20 other fields...

           }
}
```

Comment: the 3rd party push data directly to your database ? not by webservices ? if yes , why .

Comment: 3rd party pushes data to redis database hosted on redis-labs

Comment: so why you need to wait a "peak time " , why you not make a lisner on the queues ? when the 3rd party call the redis , you will trigger a ws or a statements on your side

Comment: Thank for you response. The redis database is not with us. and vendor uses it as a cache for multiple apps to pick data from(we are one of them).

Comment: We dont wait for peaktime, the scheduler runs every 10 mins. I meant there's considerable amount of data to be picked which can be like 20k reads per hour sometimes. and since it is `while($redis->llen('schema_queue'))` , 20k reads, validation and writing to local database would cause timeouts or load..